# Codeigniter invalid wrong email or password return message

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, passwords

I made a function in CodeIgniter so users can log into my page. When a user enters a wrong email or password I want to echo an error message like

For example Invalid email or password. But this is not working for me. I tried to do it with flashdata like this:

```
else {

$this->$session->$set_flashdata("Invalid email or password");
redirect("https://localhost/8800/login.php","refresh");
}
```

Comment: When you use 'refresh' it will clear message on the view. Also you not need `.php` and  `redirect(base_url('login'))` But also what Abdulla Nilam said in answer

Comment: Make sure you have also set the base url in config.php

Comment: `redirect('controller');` set base url in `config.php`

Answer (score 2):

is should be

```
else {

$this->session->set_flashdata('error','Invalid email or password');
redirect(base_url()); # or redirect('login'); controller name
}
```

and in view

```
if(!empty($this->session->flashdata('error'))
{
    echo $this->session->flashdata('error');
}
```

Comment: Code in the view u write is wrong. I'm getting error.

Comment: whats the error. im using it and still didnt get any error

Comment: line and post the code as well. its not code error its on your text error

Comment: No I copied that exact same piece of code and put it in my view file like this: <?php if(!empty($this->session->flashdata('error'))
{
    echo $this->session->flashdata('error');
{   ?>         And it says syntax error unexpected {

Comment: change the last `{` to `}`

Comment: I did it and it still says the first curly brace is unexpected. I don't know why its not working

Comment: check th line. not in mine

Comment: what do you mean th line?

Comment: wht is the line number and whts on it. sho the code

Comment: It says on the line of the first curly brace of you're code

Comment: This is the complete error: syntax error, unexpected '(' on line number 12.